# How to create configuration for only one project in solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have a Visual Studio c++ solution that contains multiple projects:

- MainLib (lib that uses other libs)
- Lib1
- Lib2
- ...

I have standard configurations: 'Release' and 'Debug'. Now I created new configuration 'Test' and I want this configuration to be used in MainLib (for unit tests only). Is it possible to use 'Debug' configuration in Lib1,Lib2... when 'Test' is active and how to do it? I don't want to remember about creating configuration when adding a new library.

Answer (score 0):

Whether MainLib with configuration "Test" uses the "Debug" Configuration of the other Libs only depends on your linker settings in "Test" for MainLib. If you use the debug Libs, it's fine and you are done. If so, you don't have to specify anything for configuration "Test" for the other Libs. It would even be possible to link to release libs in the "Debug" Configuration of MainLib if someone wanted to do so.